# How to enable the "Show Notification as Pop Up" by default on android devices?

Tags: android, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I am working on a food delivery app with Flutter. I have recently implemented the flutter_local_notifications and the notification is working fine. But there's one problem is that the notification doesn't show as a pop-up by default. The "Show as pop-up" option is disabled by default in the notification settings.

Is there any way the "Show as pop up" option is enabled when the app is installed by default?

**Here's my Notification Configuration Code:**

```
void registerNotification() {
    // This function registers the user for receiving push notifications.
    // After registering the user, it creates a new field inside the 'userForChat' Database
    // The field is called: 'pushToken' which is later used to configure Firebase Automatic Cloud Messaging
    firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions();

    firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
        print('onMessage: $message');
        Platform.isAndroid
            ? showNotification(message['notification'])
            : showNotification(message['aps']['alert']);
        return;
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
        print('onResume: $message');
        return;
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
        print('onLaunch: $message');
        return;
      },
    );

    // Token for Firebase Messaging
    firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token) {
      print('token: $token');

      Firestore.instance
          .collection('usersForChat')
          .document(currentUserId)
          .updateData(
              {'pushToken': token}); //Sets the firebase Token into the database
    }).catchError((onError) {
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  void configLocalNotification() {

    var initializationSettingsAndroid = AndroidInitializationSettings(
        'mipmap/ic_launcher'); 
    var initializationSettingsIOS = IOSInitializationSettings();
    var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
        initializationSettingsAndroid, initializationSettingsIOS);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);
  }

  void showNotification(message) async {
    // This function takes the notfication message as input triggers the notification to show the message.
    // The input is in a json format so you have to decode the json with dart:convert.

    // IMPORTANT: Specify the Application package name according to the OS.
    //For Android, Use the android app package name from firebase
    //For iOS, Use the iOS app package name from firebase

    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
      // add your apps package name for each OS(Android:iOS)
      Platform.isAndroid
          ? 'com.jexmovers.app' //Update the package name to your app's package names
          : 'com.jexmovers.ios', //Update the package name to your app's package names
      'JexMovers Chat',
      'App that lets you contact your food delivery person',
      playSound: true,
      enableVibration: true,
      importance: Importance.Max,
      priority: Priority.Max,
      visibility: NotificationVisibility.Public,
      enableLights: true,
    );

    var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails();
    var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
        androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);

    print(message);

    print(message['body'].toString());
    print(json.encode(message));

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      0,
      message['title'].toString(),
      message['body'].toString(),
      platformChannelSpecifics,
      payload: json.encode(message),
    );
  }
```

Comment: did you got the solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

To enable the "Show as pop up" option by default for local notifications, you can include the fullScreenIntent parameter

```
var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
  Platform.isAndroid
      ? 'com.jexmovers.app'
      : 'com.jexmovers.ios',
  'JexMovers Chat',
  'App that lets you contact with your food delivery person',
  playSound: true,
  enableVibration: true,
  importance: Importance.Max,
  priority: Priority.Max,
  visibility: NotificationVisibility.Public,
  enableLights: true,
  fullScreenIntent: true, // Enable pop-up by default
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no direct way to enable the "Show as pop-up" option by default in notification settings. This is because notification settings and preferences are platform-specific and managed by the user's system settings.

However, you can implement strategies to encourage users to enable pop-up notifications for your app:

1. In-app guidance:
   Welcome screen: Briefly explain the importance of pop-up notifications for receiving timely order updates and delivery details. Include a prominent button to navigate them directly to the notification settings.
   First notification received: When the first notification appears, show a subtle overlay explaining the benefits of pop-up notifications and provide a one-click option to navigate to the settings.
2. Permission request:
   When displaying the notification permission request after app installation, offer an extra checkbox or toggle alongside the standard "Allow Notifications" option. Label it clearly as "Show notifications as pop-ups" or similar. This reinforces the importance of pop-up notifications and gives users a specific choice.